# Databricks UDF calling an external web service cannot be serialised (PicklingError)

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, pickle, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Databricks and have a column in a dataframe that I need to update for every record with an external web service call. In this case it is using the Azure Machine Learning Service SDK and does a service call. This code works fine when not run as a UDF in spark (ie. just python) however it throws a serialization error when I try to call it as a UDF. The same happens if I use a lambda and a map with an rdd.

The model uses fastText and can be invoked fine from Postman or python via a normal http call or using the WebService SDK from AMLS - it's just when it is a UDF that it fails with this message:

TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects

The only workaround I can think of is to loop through each record in the dataframe sequentially and update the record with a call, however this is not very efficient. I don't know if this is a spark error or because the service is loading a fasttext model. When I use the UDF and mock a return value it works though.

Error at bottom...

```
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice, AciWebservice
from azureml.core import Workspace

def predictModelValue2(summary, modelName, modelLabel):  
    raw_data = '[{"label": "' + modelLabel + '", "model": "' + modelName + '", "as_full_account": "' + summary + '"}]'
    prediction = service.run(raw_data)
    return prediction

from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

predictModelValueUDF = udf(predictModelValue2)

DVIRCRAMFItemsDFScored1 = DVIRCRAMFItemsDF.withColumn("Result", predictModelValueUDF("Summary", "ModelName", "ModelLabel"))
```

> TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 2 x = df.withColumn("Result", predictModelValueUDF("Summary",
>   "ModelName", "ModelLabel"))
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in wrapper(*args)
>       194         @functools.wraps(self.func, assigned=assignments)
>       195         def wrapper(*args):
>   --> 196             return self(*args)
>       197 
>       198         wrapper.**name** = self._name
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in **call**(self, *cols)
>       172 
>       173     def **call**(self, *cols):
>   --> 174         judf = self._judf
>       175         sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
>       176         return Column(judf.apply(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column)))
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in _judf(self)
>       156         # and should have a minimal performance impact.
>       157         if self._judf_placeholder is None:
>   --> 158             self._judf_placeholder = self._create_judf()
>       159         return self._judf_placeholder
>       160
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in _create_judf(self)
>       165         sc = spark.sparkContext
>       166 
>   --> 167         wrapped_func = _wrap_function(sc, self.func, self.returnType)
>       168         jdt = spark._jsparkSession.parseDataType(self.returnType.json())
>       169         judf = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.UserDefinedPythonFunction(
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in _wrap_function(sc,
>   func, returnType)
>        33 def _wrap_function(sc, func, returnType):
>        34     command = (func, returnType)
>   ---> 35     pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
>        36     return sc._jvm.PythonFunction(bytearray(pickled_command), env, includes, sc.pythonExec,
>        37                                   sc.pythonVer, broadcast_vars, sc._javaAccumulator)
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc,
>   command)    2461     # the serialized command will be compressed by
>   broadcast    2462     ser = CloudPickleSerializer()
>   -> 2463     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)    2464     if len(pickled_command) >
>   sc._jvm.PythonUtils.getBroadcastThreshold(sc._jsc):  # Default 1M
>   2465         # The broadcast will have same life cycle as created
>   PythonRDD
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py in dumps(self, obj)
>       709                 msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.**class**.**name**, emsg)
>       710             cloudpickle.print_exec(sys.stderr)
>   --> 711             raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
>       712 
>       713
>
> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle
>   _thread._local objects

Comment: What is the type of your returned variable prediction from predictModelValue2 function if called directly (without spark)? If its something other than string then you may need to provide it accordingly in udf declaration.

Comment: Prediction is a float - I'll try it explicitly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert in DataBricks or Spark, but pickling functions from the local notebook context is always problematic when you are touching complex objects like the `service` object. In this particular case, I would recommend removing the dependency on the azureML `service` object and just use `requests` to call the service.

Pull the key from the service:

```
# retrieve the API keys. two keys were generated.
key1, key2 = service.get_keys()
scoring_uri = service.scoring_uri
```

You should be able to use these strings in the UDF directly without pickling issues -- [here is an example](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/9233ce089afb81d466076e36e7e61c3ce4cfafec/how-to-use-azureml/ml-frameworks/chainer/deployment/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-chainer/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-chainer.ipynb) of  how you would call the service with just requests. Below applied to your UDF:

```
import requests, json
def predictModelValue2(summary, modelName, modelLabel):  
  input_data = json.dumps({"summary": summary, "modelName":, ....})

  headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key1}

  # call the service for scoring
  resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, input_data, headers=headers)

  return resp.text[1]
```

On a side node, though: your UDF will be called for each row in your data frame and each time it will make a network call -- that will be very slow. I would recommend looking for ways to batch the execution. As you can see from your constructed json `service.run` will accept an array of items, so you should call it in batches of 100s or so.

Comment: Thanks, this is something along the lines I was thinking of - switching to the Request library instead of using the SDK... however I didn't think of using the SDK to get the keys and URL - that's a great idea.

Comment: And yes, I agree, it's not ideal! I think I might need to change my approach and switch to azure functions or run them asynchronously. Ah, I also didn't know that I could pass them in as batch - that's another good idea, ta.